# Wordpress: Adding a Custom HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

A friend asked me to create a webpage for their wordpress website. I've created the page using raw HTML, CSS, and Javascript. However, when I log in to their wordpress account online I cannot figure out how to upload the file or even make a link to it?

Help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

NOTE I don't know if this helps, but they are also using SEO Yoast

Comment: yoast has nothing to do with this. You should do this using the standard WP tools. Create a page first and put the content in there. If you need custom layout you can make a template by giving it a name like page-custom.php and at the top of the file include a php comment `/* Template name: Custom Page */` - that will then be selectable as the page template in the edit page. Or do you mean you don't know how to FTP the file to the site?

Comment: WordPress is a Content Management System (CMS). You create webpages inside WordPress. If you need to add special CSS and Javascript, then you are talking about more than just a webpage.

Comment: Many themes come with a custom page/template.  Download WordPress files to local machine and replace code with what you have built. I think it has to be saved as a PHP file...it's been a while since I've done this. For a walk through check out this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the theme directory: `/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/`

Create a file here which will be your custom page template, e.g: `customtemplate.php`

Start the file off with the following, which will allow you to select this template from within WordPress: `<?php /* Template name: Custom Page */ ?>`

Create the WordPress loop if needed (this will allow whatever you type in the admin to display on the website):

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

Now from the page edit screen on the right, select TEMPLATE - and choose your template name, as defined in step 3.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the right idea. However, I'm a wordpress newbie. Could you help walk me through some of the main steps like downloading the live website and then how to sync the changes I make on my local machine?